# Trying to remember a Sci-fi movie or TV series where a human space fighter pilot chases an alien space fighter craft to the edge of a black hole

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, tv, black-hole

Trying to remember a movie or TV series.

One scene I remember. The space fighter pilot is part of a squadron that has had a group dogfight with a bunch of nasty alien craft. One alien craft escapes so 1 pilot chases the alien craft to the edge of a black hole of sorts (could be a collapsing star), but the pilot gets caught in the gravitational field and gets slowly sucked in. He tries reverse thrusters and no luck. As he’s getting sucked in to the depths, he plays a Jonny Cash Burning Ring of Fire song (I think) over the radio and the song slowly gets all distorted (like batteries going flat in a walkman) from the gravitational field.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you watch this?  Can you describe any of the visuals, like the shape of the fighter?

Comment: Hey @DavidW, saw the Movie/Tv series in the mid to late 90’s. I can’t recall the type of the spacecraft involved, but Clara has identified the Tv series as per below. Thanks muchly for your interest in trying to solve the riddle….

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This sounds like the 5th episode of *[Space Above and Beyond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space:_Above_and_Beyond)*, entitled "Ray Butts".

Quoting from this [summary](https://boltax.blogspot.com/2011/04/bishs-review-space-above-and-beyond.html):

> It becomes clear that the Chigs are trying to corral the squadron
> towards a nearby black hole. Their fighters can operate in its wash
> but the Hammerheads cannot. Butts orders the 58th to go on ahead and
> turns to face them. He takes out the Chigs but cannot escape the pull
> of the black hole. His plane is pulled apart to the strains of Johnny
> Cash's **I Walk The Line**

The sequence is available on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uLQhKLPwUp4).

Comment: Hey @Clara, That’s it!! Thanks heaps, just watched it on YouTube. Thanks for that, been bugging me for a couple of years. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad to help @Phoenix11 - as soon as I read "black hole" and "Johnny Cash" the scene immediately popped into my memeory

Comment: I was quite bemused that they used "Walk the Line" instead of "Ring of Fire".

Comment: Walk the Line is about a man proud of his behavior. Ring of Fire is about a man suffering from his bad choices. Very different implications for a dying hero -- "F***all y'all anyways" vs. "Oh no what have I done?"